# How to fix os.path error in windows machine?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that will send email with or without attachment based on the attachment file input but its failing with file not found error.

Here is my function

```
def sendEmail(TO, FROM, SUBJECT, BODY, *FILETOSEND):
"""Function to send email"""

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
msg["Subject"] = SUBJECT
msg["From"] = FROM
msg["To"] = TO


if FILETOSEND:
    file_string = str(FILETOSEND)

    finalFile = file_string[1 : len(file_string) - 2]

    fp = open(finalFile)
    attachment = MIMEText(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename=fp)
    msg.attach(attachment)

# Create the body of the message
text = BODY
part1 = MIMEText(text, "plain")
msg.attach(part1)

# Send the message via local SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP("smtpservername")
s.sendmail(msg["From"], msg["To"], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

fileToSend = r"C:\Users\n123456\Desktop\DomainFolder\D1\NEWDATASET.txt"
sendEmail(TO, FROM, SUBJECT, BODY, *FILETOSEND)

I have passed all the arguments without filetosend and it worked but when passing with fileToSend its failing with OSerror

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 
"'C:\\\\Users\\\\n123456\\\\Desktop\\\\DomainFolder\\\\D1\\\\NEWDATASET.txt'"
```

I have tested with placing file in different directory and drive also with putting forward slash but still same issue.
As *FILETOSEND will return tuple I am trying string manipulation to make it correct path but no luck.
I am using windows 10 with Python 3.8. Seeking help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use path like this

```
open(r"C:\Users\n123456\Desktop\DomainFolder\D1\NEWDATASET.txt","r")
```

Comment: Actually this is a part of a bigger program where another function returning the filepath. Its failing at fp = open(finalFile) . I can not hard code the path.

Comment: Any other suggestions please ? Tried a lot of option but no luck.